# i have been writing a trigger to Throw Error on deletion of Primary Contact if linked with Registration and i am facing below errors

Tags: apex

```
public static void RestrictIsPrimaryOpportunityContactRoleBeforeDeleteWhenRegistrationIsActive(Map<id, OpportunityContactRole> ContactRoleMap)
    {
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (OpportunityContactRole OppConRole : ContactRoleMap.Values())
        {
            oppIds.add(OppConRole.opportunityId);
        }
        map<id,map<id,OpportunityContactRole>> mapOppToContactRoles = new map<id,map<id,OpportunityContactRole>> ();
        List<OpportunityContactRole> ContactList= [SELECT ID,OpportunityId,ContactId,IsPrimary FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN : oppIds];
        for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : ContactList)
        {
            if(mapOppToContactRoles.containsKey(ocr.OpportunityId))
            {
                mapOppToContactRoles.put(ocr.OpportunityId,new map<id,OpportunityContactRole>());
                system.debug('mapOppToContactRoles   ' +mapOppToContactRoles);
            }
               mapOppToContactRoles.get(ocr.OpportunityId).put(ocr.id,ocr);
        }
        Map<id, map<id,Registration__c>> mapofRegistrations = new Map<id, map<id,Registration__c>>();
        List<Registration__c> RegistrationList= [SELECT ID,Opportunity__c,Active__c FROM Registration__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : oppIds];
        for(Registration__c reg : RegistrationList)
        {
            if(mapofRegistrations.containsKey(reg.Opportunity__c))
            {
                 mapofRegistrations.put(reg.Opportunity__c,new map<id,Registration__c>());
                 system.debug('mapofRegistrations   ' +mapofRegistrations);
            }
                 mapofRegistrations.get(reg.Opportunity__c).put(reg.id,reg);
        }
        for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : ContactRoleMap)
        {
            if(mapOppToContactRoles.get(ocr.OpportunityId).IsPrimary)
            {
                for(Registration__c reg : mapofRegistrations.get(reg.Opportunity__c))
                {
                    if(reg.ContactName__c == mapOppToContactRoles.get(ocr.OpportunityId).ContactId && reg.Active__c){
                        ocr.addError('Primary Contact Role Cannot be Deleted when Registration is active');
                   }
                }
            }
        }          
    }
```

variable does not exists IsPrimary,Reg,ContactID

Answer (score 0):

In your final `for` loop, you have several instances where you have lines like `mapOppToContactRoles.get(ocr.OpportunityId).IsPrimary`

You defined `mapOppTpContactRoles` as a `Map<Id, Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole>>`, so `mapOppToContactRoles.get(ocr.OpportunityId)` is returning a `Map<Id, OpportunityContactRole>`

Your code is evaluating to `<a map>.IsPrimary`, and Maps do not have any fields. Hence, your error. You need to get down to an actual OpportunityContactRole (by using an additional `.get()`, `map.get().get()`, or using the `ocr` loop variable).